# Codeigniter4 Shared web hosting. Issue with configuring URLs

Tags: .htaccess, routes, codeigniter-4

here is the thing. localhost development works fine. as I move to shared hosting try to configure codeigniter4 I'm facing issues with routes.

I use **softaculouse** to install CI4 on the main directory (public_html). when I try to configure the routes things work fine except
when I write the domain name.

**example**

`https://example.com/`    (Issue) it will send me to `https://example.com/public/` (Code 500)
I contacted support they claim the issue in public folder I'm not allowed to add `.htaccess` so they deleted it for me `.htaccess` file in public. things work fine. however; when I write `https://example.com/`  works but the URL in the address bar changes to  `https://example.com/public`

**How to remove /public   ?**
is it a `.htaccess` configuration?

is it an issue with Apache configuration from hosting company side?

by the way

`https://example.com/home` (No problem)

`https://example.com/en` (No Problem) after modifying routes using {locale}

htaccess in public_html

```
# To prevent access to .env and other files
<Files .*>
# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
</Files>

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://example.com/public
</IfModule>
```

This is htaccess which initially was generated inside public folder (Its standard generated by composer i think)

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Comment: "I'm not allowed to add .htaccess so they deleted it for me .htaccess file in public." - Not "allowed"? So what are the differences with your localhost development? Please edit your question to include your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @MrWhite i have included htaccess files as per your request. I hope you could help. thx